# How can I programmatically set dataSource of UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am having a strange problem. I am trying to assign a dataSource to a table programatically.

I have created a `UITableView` and an IBOutlet for it in my ViewController using the Interface Builder. I have created a class that implements `UITableViewDataSource`. I set the `dataSource` of my table to be an instance of the dataSource. Everything compiles and runs fine, until the line that sets the dataSource is executed in runtime.

The error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)` and the `class AppDelegate` definition line is highlighted.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let ds = MyData()
        table.dataSource = ds // <---- Runtime error
        table.reloadData()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // ... other methods
}


class MyData: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel.text = "a row"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I am getting this runtime error? I am using XCode 6 beta 4 with Swift.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the `dataSource` delegate is usually a `weak` property, and you are not keeping your `ds` alive with a strong pointer outside of the scope, so that will be released immediately when the `–viewDidLoad()` runs out of its own scope... that may cause your problem here.

Comment: @holex I was thinking exactly the same. The solution is to move the line: let ds = MyData() out of the viewDidLoad, just below IBOutlet weak var table:UItableView

Comment: Thanks @holex and @Greg. Yes, that was the reason. So, is it meaningful to say that the we are setting `table.dataSource` by reference, not by value? If it was set by value would the code have worked?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var dataSource: MyData?

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = MyData()
        table.dataSource = dataSource!
    }
}
```

Your app breaks because the `ds` is deallocated as soon as `viewDidLoad` returns. You have to keep a reference to your data source.

Comment: saved my day. any particular reason why it only works if you declare it as a global variable?

Comment: @user431791 UITableView's dataSource is weak so there must a strong reference somewhere, in this case the class variable

Comment: makes perfect sense @SteveKuo

Comment: @user431791 it is a bit late, and maybe you understand it now, but this is not a global variable. This is an instance variable.