# Dynamic DataSource swap for UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS/Swift development, and having a problem with making a dynamic swap of DataSource work for a UITableView - note I am not swapping the Delegate, just the DataSource.

I have read other similar questions/responses on Stack Overflow, and not found one that's relevant to my situation. Typically they're about setting the DataSource on "viewDidLoad" (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075646/how-can-i-programmatically-set-datasource-of-uitableview), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806402/dynamic-datasource-delegates-for-uitableview-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)), whereas my situation is about swapping the DataSource when the user presses a button. The problems in the referenced questions don't exist in my code.

Here's outline of my code. I have the buttonPress method connected to the TouchUpInside event in the storyboard:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    ...    

    @IBAction func buttonPress(sender: UIButton) {

        ...

        self.tableView.dataSource = DummyDataSource()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    ...

}
```

...and here's my datasource class:

```
import UIKit

class DummyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    let names = ["A", "B", "C"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                     numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                     cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?

        if ( cell == nil ) {
            cell = UITableViewCell( style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default,
                                reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
        }

        cell!.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
        return cell!

    }

}
```

When I press the button, I can see that the pressButton method is being called correctly, but the data doesn't show up in the tableView (no errors - just no data). Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: Use the debugger. Are the data source methods of your `DummyDataSource` being called?

Comment: you cannot just init and assign the data source class. make an instance and then assign.

Comment: @rmaddy - I just put a print in the count and new cell methods in my DummyDataSource, and I saw that the count method does indeed get called.

Comment: @mahesh-agrawala doesn't self.tableView.dataSource = DummyDataSource() make and instance and assign it in one step?

Comment: @nickpharris mostly no.

Comment: OK... @mahesh-agrawala thanks. I changed to put an instance variable at the top of the ViewController class, and created a new instance there. And then just assigned the datasource to be that in the button method. But I don't understand why my version didn't work... can you explain that please? Thanks.

Comment: @nickpharris My answer explains it all.  Just leave a comment on the answer if there's any further clarification needed.

Comment: welcome, finally you got your problem resolved. its explained by @nhgrif below..thats it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UITableView`'s `dataSource` property is either `unsafe_unretained` or `weak`, [depending on which version of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/UIKit.html).  Either way, as with any other delegate, it doesn't keep a strong reference.

So when you write a line like this:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = DummyDataSource()
```

Your newly instantiated `DummyDataSource()` property doesn't have any strong references pointing to it.  It is therefore immediately released by ARC.

We need to keep a strong reference to the data source if we want it to stick around.

My recommendation would be to add a data source property to your view controller which can keep the strong reference.  We will also use the `didSet` of this property to set the table view's data source property and reload its data.

```
var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? {
    didSet {
        tableView?.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

We use optional-chaining to protect against the data source being set before the view is loaded and the `tableView` property is populated.  Otherwise, we will get a fatal error for trying to unwrap `nil`.

We shouldn't need to be setting the data source property on the table view anywhere else.  And the only reason why we should need to called `reloadData()` anywhere else is if our data source itself can change the data it is representing.  However, it is important that `reloadData()` is called in sync with resetting the `dataSource` to protect against some likely index-out-of-bound crashes.

Comment: Actually it is `weak` in newer iOS releases.

Comment: Do you know when that changed?

Comment: Since iOS 9: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/UIKit.html.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added that link to the answer.

Comment: There are a couple of rare cases where the delegate reference is strong. You might want to change your answer to say "as with almost all delegates..."

Comment: Just three words: "I love you"