# How to retrieve firestore data and populate Tableview Rows/Sections from a dictionary?

Tags: ios, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I'm trying to populate the Sections and Rows of my tableview using Firestore data that I've parsed and stored inside of a dictionary, that looks like this...

```
dataDict = ["Monday": ["Chest", "Arms"], "Wednsday": ["Legs", "Arms"], "Tuesday": ["Back"]]
```

To be frank, I'm not even sure if I'm supposed to store the data inside of a dictionary as I did. Is is wrong to do that? Also, since the data is being pulled asynchronously, how can I populate my sections and rows only *after* the dictionary is fully loaded with my network data? I'm using a completion handler, but when I try to print the results, of the `dataDict`, it prints out three arrays in succession, like so...

```
["Monday": ["Chest", "Arms"]]
["Tuesday": ["Back"], "Monday": ["Chest", "Arms"]]
["Tuesday": ["Back"], "Monday": ["Chest", "Arms"], "Wednsday": ["Legs", "Arms"]]
```

Whereas I expected it to return a single print of the array upon completion. What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

```
var dataDict : [String:[String]] = [:]


//MARK: - viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    vcBackgroundImg()
    navConAcc()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        self.userIdRef = user!.uid
        self.colRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days")

        self.loadData { (done) in
            if done {
                print(self.dataDict)
            } else {
                print("Error retrieving data")
            }
        }

    }

}

//MARK: - Load Data
func loadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){
        self.colRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                completion(false)
            }
            else {
                //Appending all Days collection documents with a field of "dow" to daysarray...
                for dayDocument in snapshot!.documents {
                    self.daysArray.append(dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? "")
                    self.dayIdArray.append(dayDocument.documentID)


                    Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayDocument.documentID)/Workouts/").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
                        if let err = err
                        {
                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                            completion(false)
                        }
                        else {
                            //Assigning all Workouts collection documents belonging to selected \(dayDocument.documentID) to dictionary dataDict...
                            for document in snapshot!.documents {

                                if self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] == nil {
                                    self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] = [document.data()["workout"] as? String ?? ""]
                                } else {
                                    self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""]?.append(document.data()["workout"] as? String ?? "")
                                }
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                                // print(self.dataDict)
                            }
                            completion(true)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.dayCount =  snapshot?.count ?? 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried putting `DispatchQueue.main.async {` above `if self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] == nil {`? still getting a handle on your code, but maybe include the storing of the data in the async call, along with the `reloadData` call.

Comment: these lines: `picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self` don't refer to anything, you need to set the tableview delegate to have a `dataSource` how you are with `picker` only `picker` isn't your tableview? if it is, where is the declaration for it?

Comment: I don't really think you should store your data in a dictionary for a tableview like this either, it makes more sense to have an array. Its easier to conceptualize, when the tableview is formed, it loops through the array and takes each slot in the array, and puts it in a row. You can store objects in an array.

Comment: like the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075646/how-can-i-programmatically-set-datasource-of-uitableview

Comment: I know that you can't see it in the code, but I'm actually using a UITableViewController, so I don't need to set delegates or datasources, they are implicitly set by the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just the flow of your program. Every time you loop through the collection, you add what it gets to the dictionary. So on the first pass, it will print that the dictionary has 1 item. On the second pass, it adds another item to the dictionary, and then prints the dictionary, which now has 2 items in it, so 2 items are printed. I don't think you are seeing unexpected behavior, it is just how you have your log statement ordered with how you are looping.

In other words, it makes sense that it is printing like that.

Comment: Exactly. And the completion gets called once per document (in this case three times), which is usually not the expected behavior.

Comment: Its all in the floooooo

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ewizard's answer. The problem is in the flow of your program. You iterate through the documents and you fetch the documents in the collection for every iteration. You also reload the tableView and call completion closure multiple times, which you don't want to do.

To improve the flow of your program try using DispatchGroup to fetch your data and then put it together one once, when all the data is fetched. See example below to get the basic idea. My example is a very simplified version of your code where I wanted to show you the important changes you should preform.

```
func loadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    self.colRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        // Handle error

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var fetchedData = [Any]()

        // Iterate through the documents
        for dayDocument in snapshot!.documents {
            // Enter group
            group.enter()
            // Fetch data
            Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayDocument.documentID)/Workouts/").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
                // Add your data to fetched data here
                fetchedData.append(snapshot)
                // Leave group
                group.leave()
            }
        }

        // Waits for until all data fetches are finished
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            // Here you can manipulate fetched data and prepare the data source for your table view
            print(fetchedData)

            // Reload table view and call completion only once
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

I also agree with other comments that you should rethink the data model for your tableView. A much more appropriate structure would be a 2d array (an array of arrays - first array translates to the table view sections and the inner array objects translate to section items).
Here's an example:

```
// Table view data source
[
    // Section 0
    [day0, day1],
    // Section 1
    [day2, day3],
    // Section 2
    [day4, day5],
]
```

Example of usage:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

}
```